# Error in httpwebrequest Exception Handling

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am posting JSON data to API. If I post wrong data, `catch` block is not catching error. Controls stops at `using (httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())` this point and shows error. What wrong I am doing.
Following is my code,

```
try
        {

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ipaddress");
            httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string name = objTSPost.name;
                string servicetype = objTSPost.service_type;
                string json = "{\"name\":\"VMR_" + name + "\"," +
                              "\"service_type\":\"" + servicetype + "\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }


            using (httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                string str = "{\"name\":\"VMR_" + objTSPost.name + "\"," +
                                  "\"service_type\":\"" + objTSPost.service_type + "\"}";
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TSGetRootObject>(str);
                data.status = ((HttpWebResponse)httpResponse).StatusDescription;
                return data;
            }

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            objTSPost.status = ex.Message;
            return objTSPost;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post some details about the error you are getting? The message, the type of the exception?

Comment: Use more generic Exception instead of WebException if catch is NOT catching.

Comment: You are catching exceptions of type webexception only. It might be throwing some other type of exception, thats why its not being caught. I suggest, you should add another catch block of generic type "Exception". Something like this catch (Exception ex)
        {
            objTSPost.status = ex.Message;
            return objTSPost;
        }

Comment: Following error i am getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: How to handle these type of errors

Comment: Thanks @sachin for your advice

Answer (score 2):

Sachin is correct, you should handle exceptions from the most specific to the least specific exception.

Also it is not a good practice propagating the exception message to the users since it might reveal security vulnerabilities, instead I suggest you log the actual message and propagate a standard userfriendly message instead. Maybe you are doing that after the method returns it's value but since the rest of the code is not available I'd just like to give you a heads up on it.

```
    try
    {

        //My maybe not toally reliable code

    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        LogMessage(ex.Message);
        objTSPost.status = "My custom userfriendly specific web exception message";
        return objTSPost;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessage(ex.Message);
        objTSPost.status = "My custom userfriendly unhandled exception message";
        return objTSPost;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @JFM for your valuable suggesstion.